# How do I add a user-agent to this code so that I don't get error 403 exceptions anymore? I'm trying to scrape data for a stock screener

Tags: java, screen-scraping, stock

```
stockURL = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&f=cap_smallover&ft=4&c=0,1,2,6,7,10,11,13,14,45,65';

buffer = java.io.BufferedReader(...
    java.io.InputStreamReader(...
    openStream(...
    java.net.URL(stockURL))));
```

I don't know how to go about this^ at all, so any other suggestions or improvements to the code would be welcome. Here is another thread that wasn't answered https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/434084-reading-in-stock-data-from-a-website

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in a while.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/foobar");
    URLConnection hc = url.openConnection();
    hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", " ");
```

You'll use your user agent as the second parameter, where I have the space.